# Is branch coverage the same as decision coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

I'm learning software testing right now, and I found that there are a lot of coverage criterias out there. And something just confused me.

**Is branch coverage equals to decision coverage?**
wiki said it's not the same [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage#Modified_condition.2Fdecision_coverage), I read the reference document, but I didn't found something such as: `branch coverage` is not `decision coverage`, maybe it's because my poor English...

But other tutors all says `branch coverage` is `decision coverage`. So can anyone give me a clear answer about this? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly. As ISTQB Foundation book gives,
*branch coverage is closely related to decision coverage and at
100% coverage they give exactly the same results. Decision coverage measures
the coverage of conditional branches; branch coverage measures the coverage
of both conditional and unconditional branches. The Syllabus uses decision
coverage, as it is the source of the branches. Some coverage measurement
tools may talk about branch coverage when they actually mean decision
coverage. (c) ISTQB foundation book.*

Decision coverage [image: example]:

Hope now It comes clear for you)

Comment: They are not the same with 100% coverage. Think of something like "if (a == X || b == Y) abc else xyz". With branch condition you can never reach b == Y, and even this way get 100% coverage. With decision condition you need to pass trough both a == X and b == Y cases.

Comment: @Hugo Tavares No, that would be condition coverage. Decision coverage does not care about sub-expressions, just the decision - which is either true or false.